# React: Avoid re-rendering of Component on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[HERE IS A GIST](https://gist.github.com/tumanov-alex/26e6cc5b42e7c5ed3d04c72f6beca24c)

This small program paints a random shape where you clicked.
When you click on some shape it should be deleted.

Deletion works, but after that all the shapes get re-rendered. How to avoid re-rendering of shapes?

Comment: Do other shapes also get deleted when it rerenders?

Comment: So dont worry with it. Its a principle of React, that whenever there is a change in state, then the component and it sub-components gets rerendered. But in case you need to handle the re-rendering yourself then you can use `shouldComponentUpdate` function provided by React. It is called whenever the React Component is about to re-render.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, generate id and use that id as key instead I think React DOM renders the elements based on key:

```
constructor(props) { 
 super(props); 
 this.id = 0; // add id
 ....
} 

addShape(e) { 
 ...     
 updatedShapes.push({ 
   x: e.clientX, 
   y: e.clientY,
  id: this.id++ 
 }); 
 ...
} 

randomShape(shape)
{
  ...
  <circle ... key={shape.id} .../>;
  ...
}
```